# Accordion table cell - How to dynamically expand/contract uitableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying create an accordion type of uitableviewcell that, when the user selects the cell, it expands to display a detailed info view inline similar to how the digg app works. I initially tried replacing the current tablecell with a customcell in cellForRowAtIndex, however the animation looks a bit choppy as you can see the cell being replaced and overall the effect doesn't work too well.

If you look at the digg app and others who have done this it seems that they aren't replacing the current cell but instead perhaps adding a subview to the cell? The original cell however doesn't seem to animate at all and only the new view accordions into the table.

Does anyone have any ideas how to accomplish a similar effect?

I have made some progress using neha's method below and while the cell is animating the correct way it is wreaking havoc with the other cells in the table. What I have done is subclassed UITableViewCell with a custom class which contains an instance of a UIView which actually draws the view which I then add to the table cell's contentview.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

if (selected) { 
    [self expandCell];
}
}

-(void)expandCell { 
    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.contentView.bounds.size.width, 110);
}
```

Here are all the table delegate methods I am using:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
if (isSearching && indexPath.row == selectedIndex) {
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchCell";
    CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    
    [cell setCustomTitle:[timeZoneNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] detail:[timeZoneNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    UILabel *theText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width -20, 22.0)];
    theText.text = @"Title Text";
    [cell.contentView addSubview:theText];


    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10 + 46.0, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width - 20, 40.0)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];        

    UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 88.0, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width - 20, 22.0)];
    testLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some text here"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:testLabel];

    [theText release];
    [textField release];
    [testLabel release];

    return cell;        
} else {
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [cell setCustomTitle:[timeZoneNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] detail:[timeZoneNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell; 
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];   

selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
isSearching = YES;


[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {        
if (isSearching && indexPath.row == selectedIndex) {
    return 110;
}
return rowHeight;           
}
```

It seems now that the cell is expanding but not actually being refreshed so the labels, and textfield aren't being shown. They do however show up when I scroll the cell off and on the screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: anyone? Not looking for detailed code but rather just some guidelines on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you make Pawel's answer the correct answer... You can't get better than that.

Answer (score 94):

The Apple way to do is quite simple.

First, you'll need to save the selected indexPath row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   self.selectedRowIndex = [indexPath retain];
   [tableView beginUpdates];
   [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

I'll explain the begin/end updated part later.

Then, when you have the currently selected index, you can tell the tableView that it should give that row more space.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   //check if the index actually exists
   if(selectedRowIndex && indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row) {
        return 100;
   }
   return 44;
}
```

This will return height 100 for the selected cell.

Now we can go back to the begin/end updates. That block triggers the reload of all tableView geometry. Moreover, that block is animated, which eventually gives the impressions of the row expanding.

Comment: hi Pawel, tried this and the animation affect is exactly what i am looking for but the issue i ran into is that this code does not call cellForRowAtIndex so i couldnt figure out how/where to modify the content of the expanded cell. It simply adjusts the height of the cell. I also tried to get the cell in didSelectRowAtIndex with:
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
and make changes to the cell and then call beginUpdates. While this works it seems to wreak havoc on the rest of the table. Can you explain where you make changes to the selected cell to avoid this?

Comment: Since you're calling the begin/end updates in didSelectCellForRowAtIndexPath: method, the cell has already been selected. Therefore you can use the setSelected:animated: method in your cell implemenetation to configure it for selected state.

Comment: Hi, i updated my code above to reflect some of these changes however it seems that if i put the code to create the new content such as labels, textfields, etc into the cellForRowAtIndex method then it doesnt work because that method is not called when you call [tableView beginUpdate] & [tableView endUpdates]. So i am not sure where to put this code and how to correctly use the setSelected: method? Any advice this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Hi Pawel, Any ideas on why this isnt working properly. Could you please give me some code snippets or something? I reeeeally want to move on to something else now :)

Comment: The begin/end updateds is the right way to do this. Don't add new views o setSelected. Instead, add them on cell creation, and set their hidden value to YES. Layout them properly in your implementation of layoutSubviews. And when you're selecting the cell, set their hidden to NO, and when deselecting to YES. There is no need for you to get the cellForRowAtIndexPath method called. You can do all the customization without it. Kind Regards, Pawel

Comment: @pawel is right, cellForRowAtIndexPath is only for creation, and reuse of cells. beginUpdates/endUpdates combines all animations and cell size changes, its the only *correct* way to change cell heights..

Answer (score 5):

Pawel's beginUpdates/endUpdates trick is good, and I often use it.  But in this case you simply need to reload the rows that are changing state, ensuring that you correctly reload them with the desired cell type, and that you return the correct new cell height.

Here is a complete working implementation of what I think you're trying to accomplish:

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ExpandingTableViewController : UITableViewController 
{

}

@property (retain) NSIndexPath* selectedIndexPath;

@end
```

.m:

```
@implementation ExpandingTableViewController
@synthesize selectedIndexPath;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    NSIndexPath* indexPathSelected = self.selectedIndexPath;

    if ( nil == indexPathSelected || [indexPathSelected compare: indexPath] != NSOrderedSame )
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"cell %d", indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] autorelease];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"cell %d", indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"(expanded!)", indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ( self.selectedIndexPath != nil && [self.selectedIndexPath compare: indexPath] == NSOrderedSame )
    {
        return tableView.rowHeight * 2;
    }

    return tableView.rowHeight;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSArray* toReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: indexPath, self.selectedIndexPath, nil];
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: toReload withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

If you don't want to reload the cell (you want to keep your existing cell and just change the size, and likely add/remove some subviews), then simply do the beginUpdates/endUpdates trick in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, and call some method on your cell to incite the layout change.  beginUpdates/endUpdates will prompt the tableView to re-query the heights for each cell - so be sure to return the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that subclasses UITableviewcell in your project. Create this class' nib and set its parent to be the class in your project with tableview and override its  -

```
(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Write methods contractCell() and expandCell() in this class, and provide the height of the cells you want in expandCell method. Call this methods appropriately based on some flags set to identify wheather the cell is in expanded state or contracted state. Use your tableview's

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

method to handle selection of cells.

Comment: neha, thx for your reponse. Could you elaborate a little on how exactly to go about this? Im still a little confused on how to use the setSelected: method? Will the tableCell automatically adjust it height after calling expandCell/contractCell and more importantly would it appear as if the selected cell is expanding and not simply being reloaded which is the initial problem i ran into? I called reoloadRowsAtIndex in didSelectRowAtIndex and while that worked you could visually see the cell being reloaded, either from the top/bottom/etc. depending on the animation style chosen.

Comment: Once you create a class that subclasses uitablviewcell, the method "(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated" automatically appears in the created class which is explicitely called whenever you select a cell in tableview. It's meant for configuring the view for selected state of cell. Make sure to also create a nib of this uitableviewcell subclass and set the parent of this nib as your tableview's class. Yes, this will give you the effect you are expecting, it will show the cells expanding/contracting and not reloading.

Comment: hi neha, thx again for replying. I seem to be making some progress however pls see above for changes i have tried and issues i am still having. Also what code exactly should go into the setSelected: method? Still trying to stumble through this unfortunately.

thx

Comment: The contents [labels, textfield etc] you want to show in your cell should be configured in tableview delegate method - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath). Keep the selected "height" logic in (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated. In expandCell() and contractCell(), only assign the cell its height and call these methods in setSelected method mentioned above. If you want dynamic height for your subviews then it also should be handled in the tableview delegate method cellForRowAtIndexpath mentioned above.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested which are shown above however the problem now is that the cell, while expanding, does not update to show the new label, textfields, etc.. This is why i initially put all the cell content stuff in expandCell because even though i call [tableView beginUpdates] in didSelectRowAtIndex the cellForRowAtIndex method is NOT called at all. Now that i have moved all the new cell content creation code back into that method it doesnt update the cell until it is shown again. Also not sure if i am correctly setting the height for the cell in expandCell:?

Comment: The cell text instead is being squashed and stretched. Arggg! This is driving me nuts, please can you show me some code on how to get this working :)   thx

Comment: I'm afraid why your cellForRowAtIndex method isn't getting called. Are you setting the tableview delegate to self? When I had done something similar I wasn't using [tableView beginUpdates], [tableView endUpdates]. Try removing them. Regarding the code, I'll try posting it tonight.

Comment: I'm sorry for such a big delay.. Thought I would develop it myself and suggest you better, but i'm very busy to even sleep... Check this stackOverflow question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810653/first-tap-on-customcell-of-uitableview-should-expand-it-and-second-should-contrac. To be clear, this question's asked by me when I was working for my earlier employer, so I don't have the code any more..

Answer (score 0):

Replace your cellForRowAtIndexPath function with this one.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath {

    if (isSearching && indexPath.row == selectedIndex) {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchCell";
       CustomTableCell *cell = [[[CustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        [cell setCustomTitle:[timeZoneNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] detail:[timeZoneNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        UILabel *theText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,
10.0, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width
-20, 22.0)];
        theText.text = @"Title Text";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:theText];


        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10 +
46.0, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width - 20, 40.0)];
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];        

        UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0,
88.0, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width - 20, 22.0)];
        testLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some text here"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:testLabel];

        [theText release];
        [textField release];
        [testLabel release];

        return cell;        
    } else {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        CustomTableCell *cell = [[[CustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        [cell setCustomTitle:[timeZoneNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] detail:[timeZoneNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        return cell; 
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

create array wof dictionary which have a key Select_sts which is 0 in start when click its change  1
accourding u change table

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 40.0)];
    UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.opaque = NO;
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 10.0, 300.0, 20.0);
    headerLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"PNR %@",[[record objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"number"]];
    customView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

btn_openClose.tag=section+10000;
    btn_openClose.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    //  [btn_openClose setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down_arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_openClose addTarget:self action:@selector(collapseExpandButtonTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [customView addSubview:btn_openClose];

}


- (void) collapseExpandButtonTap:(id) sender{
    int indexNo=[sender tag]-10000;
//    NSLog(@"total_record    %@",[total_record objectAtIndex:indexNo]);
    NSMutableDictionary *mutDictionary = [[total_record objectAtIndex:indexNo] mutableCopy];
   if([[mutDictionary objectForKey:@"Select_sts"] integerValue]==0)
       [mutDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"√"];
    else
       [mutDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"Select_sts"];

    [total_record replaceObjectAtIndex:indexNo withObject:mutDictionary];

//    [table_view beginUpdates];
//    [table_view reloadData];
//    [table_view endUpdates];

    NSMutableIndexSet *indetsetToUpdate = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc]init];
    [indetsetToUpdate addIndex:indexNo]; // [indetsetToUpdate addIndex:<#(NSUInteger)#>]
    // You can add multiple indexes(sections) here.
    [table_view reloadSections:indetsetToUpdate withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```