# What is this UI element

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, uitableview

hey I'm trying to figure out what this element is in an app I have been using it looks like the UITableView but when you click it it drops down and shows some sliders and buttons.  How do I do this in my app?

Here are a few photos to show how it works, this is what it looks like before I click the tone curve button:

[image]

Here is what it looks like after I click the tone curve button:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a totally custom object to me

Comment: It looks like a tableview that just reloads when you click a certain cell. It's custom made and I don't think you will find the code for the whole shabang anywhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066167/accordion-table-cell-how-to-dynamically-expand-contract-uitableviewcell

Comment: Thanks everyone I got this figured out now!  I just created a UITableView and when a row is touched I just increase the height and change the arrow image on it so it points down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of behaviour could be implemented using a UITableView. When the user taps the arrow, you would add a cell to the table view, probably with a row animation to animate it into place, using [`-[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a).

Alternatively, it could be a custom control inside a UIScrollView, which places the new view in place and animates its size and position to be displayed, while also animating the positions of the lower controls until they're further below.

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to tell for sure.  While it does look like `UITableView`, it could be a combination of custom objects.  With out getting an explanation from the developer or seeing the code, it is almost impossible to tell.