# accordion style menu ios

Tags: ios, user-interface, accordion

I am going to implement an iOS accordion style menu.  I am looking to see if there is something like this in the open source community before rolling my own.  Does any one know of an iOS open source accordion style UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this effect easily by using an UITableView.
Check this answer for more information

[Accordion table cell - How to dynamically expand/contract uitableviewcell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066167/accordion-table-cell-how-to-dynamically-expand-contract-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this model, and there is a link to github at the end of tutorial. It's a simple model without tones of code, classes, buggy animation, etc. http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/expandable-collapsable-accordio-uitableview/