# How do I increase the row height of a selected cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a TableViewController with Prototype Cells that look like this:
[image]

I would like to only display the Title and Date labels by default when the TableView data loads. Additionally, when the user selects a particular cell, I want the cell to expand so that the user can read the contents of the Description label (which can run over multiple lines).

I have looked through several sources on StackOverflow including the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3075493/4481169.

Most of the sources I have looked through assume that when the cell is not selected it will return to a specific height. However, the text of my Title label can take up multiple lines in some cases which means that each cell will have a different initial row height to begin with.

How can I make it so when the user selects a particular cell it expands to display all three labels and when that cell is unselected, the cell reverts to its original height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to achieve this would be having 2 cell prototypes for:

1. Not selected: with 2 UILabels; // let is be with ID: `@"NotSelectedCell"`
2. Selected: with all 3 UILabels; // `@"SelectedCell"`

Also You need to store the `indexPath` of the selected cell, so:

```
@implementation InformationTableViewController {
    NSIndexPath* selectedCellIndexPath;
}
```

In your tableView delegate method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you need to switch between `NotSelectedCell` and `SelectedCell` according to the indexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([indexPath isEqual:selectedCellIndexPath]) {
        NSString* cellIdentifier = @"SelectedCell";
        InformationTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[InformationTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        cell.title = // title
        cell.date  = // date
        cell.description = // description

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        NSString* cellIdentifier = @"NotSelectedCell";
        InformationTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[InformationTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        cell.title = // title
        cell.date  = // date

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Also you must save a new indexPath everytime user selects a new cell and reload the tableView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    selectedCellIndexPath = [indexPath copy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In order to recover the scroll position of the tableView before reload, you have to do the following:

```
CGFloat tableViewContentHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
[self.tableView reloadData];
CGFloat newTableViewContentHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, newTableViewContentHeight - tableViewContentHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, I tried this out and it worked. Is there any way to animate the change of prototype cell? Also, how can I keep the selected cell highlighted?

Comment: @ivdekov 1. You can use [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade] to animate reloading of the tableView; 2. In order to highlight the selected cell you can set a backgroundColor for the SelectedCell prototype. Please consider accepting the answer if it's the solution to your problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, I create an array of IndexPaths and store my currently selected IndexPath and my previously selected IndexPath. I then call tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths and pass in the array of IndexPaths.
Then, in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, if the indexPath == currently selected index path, I change the cell's background color.
Is it okay to do it this way?

Comment: When I select the rows at the bottom of the TableView, the screen scrolls up. Do you know how I can prevent this?

Comment: @ivdekov updated the answer; Actually you can't prevent scrolling up, so you have to scroll back down to the previous position

Comment: replace `[self.tableView reloadData]` with `[self.tableView beginUpdates]; [self.tableView endUpdates];` to animate the change and also prevent the scroll up.

Comment: @Roman Slyepko 
I ended up using the method `tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath` to scroll the tableView to the correct position after reloading the appropriate cells. Thank you for all your help :)

Comment: @Sulthan I tried replacing the `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` method with `tableView.beginUpdates()` followed by `tableView.endUpdates()` but the description does not show up. The cell gets highlighted but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement i would suggest you to do this steps

- First of don't give height constraint to description and even don't
  add any text in it i.e keep it blank
- Then when you get the values for description store in other array
- After this on delegate method for didselectrowatindex you can fill
  the value of that description and it reload it .
- So it will fill the text in description and take the height as
  required

Comment: Thanks for your response Moin. I tried implementing you solution and it works but there are glitches. When I click on the cells at the bottom of the TableView the whole table view scrolls upwards a bit.

Comment: It will scroll up as the description label is open and so it moves up

Comment: if u find the answer helpful then please accept it so even other developers like us can get help from. Thank u